# Medieval style tactics vs high-positioned archers

Tags: warfare, medieval, tactics

I am working out a situation where an army is invading a heavily wooded land, two large units of regular footmen with sword and shield and supporting archers, against a force almost exclusively of archers.

These archers though are positioned in tall, thickly wooded trees, too tall to reach with ground-based archers (think those massive California Redwoods from Star Wars). The archers are also notable for their skills in this world.

Tactical errors notwithstanding, as there's to be tragic blunders in my scenario, I remain curious if I have my thoughts right about this.

How would such a force tackle the problem outlined above?

Comment: *"Two large units of regular footmen with sword and shield":* there was no such thing in the Middle Ages, neither in Western Europe nor anywhere else. The *one and only* army which fielded large units of infantry armed primarily with swords and shields was the Roman army, from about 300 BCE to about 300 CE. (In the Middle Ages, there were *small* forces armed with swords and shields, for example some marauding Viking bands. But *large* units, no. They would have been utterly ineffective against any kind of normal medieval force; remember than the Middle Ages is the time of heavy cavalry.)

Comment: Since you gave them shields: "Shields overhead. Keep going. Set every tree with an archer in it alight as you pass it. Vassal, stay here with your element for a couple days and clean up any archers who survive the fire, smoke, and thirst."

Comment: I struggle with the idea of efficient long range combat in a dense forest.

Comment: @AlexP The Byzantine Empire continued to make heavy use sword and shield infantry well into the 10th century.  It certainly was not the whole of their army as it was for classical Rome, but they were still used here and there in significant numbers.

Comment: One comment regarding something that has come up in different answers regarding shields: Shields are most likely _not_ effective protection against medieval archers, especially when the arrows are coming from heights where gravity can counter-act velocity drop due to air friction. See this video for a demonstration of how longbow arrows can easily penetrate medieval shields: [Lockdown Longbow - Do shields stop arrows?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y6IlEUm_Eo4) With the penetration shown in that video, an army could not use hand-held shields as effective protection during any sort of march.

Comment: @2ndQuantized: (1) The man in that video was shooting a crossbow. Yes, crossbow bolds were perfectly able to penetrate shields and armor. (That's why the at one point the Pope threatened crossbowmen with excommunication.) (2) Longbows? What longbows? The archers are perched on tree limbs, how would they shoot longbows? (3) The arrows in the video did not go through the shields, they just protruded some 20 cm on the other side. That's pretty effective protection when you are shielding from arrows coming from above -- the shield would not be in contact with the body.

Comment: @Nosajimiki: Were they? I would love to see a reference that Byzantine infantry were primarily armed with swords. As far as I know, Byzantine heavy infantry were armed with pole arms, like all medieval infantry; they also carried what could be a long dagger or a very short sword (depending on how you want to present it), but that was their secondary weapon, to be used as a last ditch defense (like a pistol for modern infantry).

Comment: @AlexP (1) The person is using a crossbow that causes the arrows to leave the crossbow at the same velocity as from a longbow. (He mentions this at the beginning of the video.) The behaviour of the arrow will be dominated by the initial velocity, so it is an accurate representation of a longbow for this purpose (up to some small effects, such as oscillation from the archer's paradox). See this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l9vWXVbvOas) and this [one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BV8kt-bDxnk) for more details about what he is doing.

Comment: @AlexP (2) Since the trees are huge redwoods and the terrain is very familiar to the defenders, they could easily have platforms in the trees, from which they can fire longbows. Barring this, though, I agree that they would need to either use light crossbows or composite bows. (3) The arrows even go through the maille on the simulated arm ([see here](https://youtu.be/y6IlEUm_Eo4?t=230)). Being vulnerable to a penetrating hit in the arm will cause problems. Shields are not useless and are important, but they are not so effective that one can just raise shields and ignore archer fire (sadly...).

Comment: @Erik: 'Sylvanian Family Breakdown'. Squirrel turns against rabbit.

Comment: @AlexP Okay so, I had to do some digging, and it seems different translations of Tactica of Emperor Leo VI the Wise written at the turn of the 10th century BC read one of two ways. Either it reads "You shall equip the infantry skoutatos, formerly called hoplite, with a sword, a lance, and, when necessary, a shield of the kind called thyreos" or "You shall equip the infantry skoutatos, formerly called hoplite, with a sword and when necessary a  lance, and shield of the kind called thyreos".

Comment: One translation indicating the spear as optional, and the other implying the sword as a secondary weapon (like the Greek Hoplite). However, some artwork of the period shows soldiers fighting with sword and shield and no spear which leads me to suspect the later may be the better translation indicating they would opt out of spears when the terrain did not favor them (like if you had to fight in a forest for example).

Comment: Also, if you go back to the 8th century AD (early medieval period) there is artwork depicting the use of sword and shield infantry in the wars between the Picts and Britons, where they appear to have been used as the front-rank of infantry with spearmen behind them.  Though there is very little writing or artwork from this part of the middle ages to confirm or deny if this was at all the norm.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Medieval problems require medieval solutions: FIRE!

Either set the whole forest on fire, or just the tree where your targets are hiding (fire arrows were a thing already in medieval time).

If the trees burns, you are done.

If the tree or the shrubs on the ground do not burn promptly, they will produce enough smoke to allow your men to reach close to the tree and chop them down.

Comment: Or just have a couple of men with shields protecting the men with axes

Comment: Before modern times there were very few problems that you could not solve with fire.

Comment: @TheSquare-CubeLaw Case in point, even the problem of (forest) fires is solved with fire

Comment: I feel like setting a forest on fire while trying to march through it is a very bad idea.

Comment: @aleppke you just have to wait until the fire is out.

Comment: @TheSquare-CubeLaw Assuming it is a large forest, wouldn't the fire burn for an infernally long time?

Comment: @nobody yes. A pyro's dream.

Comment: Reminds me of the film "Robin Hood Prince of Thieves".

Comment: As I just commented on Ash's Answer, a fire would work the first time, maybe even a couple of times, but the archers would likely just make rope bridges between trees to escape. All that takes is a single rope, nothing complicated. I learned how to cross a single-rope bridge in Army Basic, and it's not that hard for people in good shape, as long-range arches would likely be.

Comment: @computercarguy and someone walking on a rope bridge will count 0 defense wise. The attackers have achieved their goal

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica, you don't walk on a single-rope bridge. If you train your archers appropriately for tree stands, you'll likely also need to train them to fire from any angle, including hanging upside down while hanging from a rope strung between trees. You'll also likely have archers in other trees being able to give suppressing fire at attackers while other archers move. This is a pretty standard tactic for any army.

Comment: Yes, they weren't conservationists with other peoples land, ashes and corpses fertilising their newly conquered land.... win win wituation

Comment: I don't think this would work. Huge trees burn very poorly (perhaps you don't know how large a redwood is, they are massive: https://i.pinimg.com/originals/5b/d7/88/5bd7880d92c15bb9a792b43c76eabc3f.jpg , https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTZ0vCYmXwPIsq0S9cTIKZSmXq5pNMo8ovmfA&usqp=CAU ) and the idea of the smoke working as concealment... you'd be roasting your own troops!

Answer (score 34):

#### Your enemy has done 90% of the work of setting up a siege for you. Help them finish it.

Many medieval battles were fought as sieges - a well fortified position, a superior force surrounding it, and you starve them out. That's what we've got here.

Short of burning the forest down, or smoking them out, or cutting down the massive trees, just wait them out. Get your archers set up with a line of sight on the base of the trees, sheltered from the sniping enemy with shields (and / or brush), and just wait for them to starve or die of thirst. As they climb down they'll be very exposed and can be easily sniped.

Be sure to have nice cookouts within smelling distance. Pig-on-a-spit will break the soul of an enemy archer whose dying of hunger and thirst as he's been trapped up a tree for 4 days waiting for a shot that he can never take.

Comment: If the archers are in the trees, they might've made walkways, storages and housing. They can also have other weapons that are a staple in these situations, like rocks or simply very heavy branches and if they're smart things like tar. With the high flexibility this would provide it would mean little parts of the woods are safe.

Comment: @Trioxidane Water is still going to be a limiting factor. If you're up a tree, you have no access to a well. All the ground force need to do is surround them. And the tree force have no defence against fire.

Comment: 'Tree Force'? Has anyone told the US President?

Comment: @Graham "Water is still going to be a limiting factor." There's a lot of rain the rainforest.

Comment: @nick012000 That could help, sure. But many places have a "wet season" and a "dry season", and a quick Google suggests Redwood National Park gets most of its rain between November and May. Historically, warfare mostly happened in the dry seasons. Bows with natural fibre strings also aren't useable in the wet, which could be an issue for the OP.

Comment: A fire would work the first time, maybe even a couple of times, but the archers would likely just make rope bridges between trees to escape. All that takes is a single rope, nothing complicated. I learned how to cross a single-rope bridge in Army Basic, and it's not that hard for people in good shape, as long-range arches would likely be.

Answer (score 29):

**Your Archers Have a Bad Time**

So my first thought is, "There's no way you could convince archers to do this."  Why?  Because of three things:

1. Being up in a tree does nothing for them, archery-wise.  You can't take a proper stance, because you're on a tree limb and worried about falling.  You can't have massed volley-fire, because the tree branches block LOS and the archers are too dispersed. You COULD ambush people (even in urban fights where we 'expect' the Bad Guy to be in upper-story windows people don't look up.  That tendency will only be exacerbated in a world where essentially none of your soldiers routinely think about "upstairs.")  But the problem with that is....
2. You can't decisively destroy the enemy force.  The Tutenbourg Forest, where German tribesman slaughtered 3 Roman Legions, is a textbook ancient ambush... that lasted 3 days.  Your archers are up trees.  You wait for The Perfect Moment.  You fire! Loose all the arrows! (probably not at your 12-shots-a-minute max speed because your archers are all up trees) Your accuracy.... isn't great.  Because it's bow-and-arrow at armored targets, in the woods, with lots of branches in the way.  Plus ancient armor is DESIGNED to stop impacts from above anyway.  Still, the enemy is disorganized, maybe some leaders are down, and they quickly fall back out of bowshot.  Now what?  Your archers clamber down 50ft of tree to chase after them?  Not fast they don't! The enemy has plenty of time to reorganize themselves.  If they even flee, which if they're smart they won't because...
3. A guy in a tree is a dead man, one way or the other.  There is a Very Good Reason you don't see this in real life beyond the very occasional lone sniper.  That's because being in a tree might be great concealment, but the second the enemy knows you're there you're at a HUGE disadvantage.  If the enemy sets fire to your tree, then what?  Or if he simply keeps a watch on you from a safe* distance. *safe being either out of bowshot or within bow-range but under a pavaise of some sort.
   Once the enemy knows you're there, exposed, on the side of a tree, it's not too terribly difficult to have their own smaller force of archers outflank you.  The enemy on the ground has shields, you have a hard-to-move-around-in tree.  You get shot. you die.  Or they go around you, you starve to death, and die.

It's point 3 that really toasts this plan.  A small ambush of 10ish guys up trees to kill 10 other guys?  MAYBE that works out.  But armies?  You want me, Joe Archer, to stay in a tree, where I can't run away if the plan goes awry, and shoot arrows?  Of which I have.... how many? Not enough to hold my position if THEIR archers kill my 6 buddies.  There's 6,000 enemies.  What if a larger-than-average force comes at my position?  I can't fall back, I can't kill them all, I probably can't even surrender fast enough.  No sir, ain't doing it!

**What you COULD Accomplish**

So how do I fight an army of mostly-infantry with a force of archers in a woodlands environment?  Simple.  I DON'T.  Not a smack-down drag-out fight anyway.  Can't meet them in a pitched battle, arrowstorms don't work in woods, and without a line of infantry to support me I can't hold a position.  So I send half the archers home, they're just mouths to feed and medieval logistics are murderous.  Instead I harass their foraging parties, kill their scouts, have 6 guys fire 2 arrows each at the head of their column then have them meld back into the woods, just for another 6 guys to do the exact same thing 10 minutes later.  Always always ALWAYS have a fallback position.  Have other archers kill or drive away all the game in the area near where they're traveling, then have yet more archers kill the oxen pulling their supply wagons.  Find a couple axes? Great! Chop down trees to slow their passage.  Which means it takes yet more supplies for them to traverse said woods.  The enemy starves, gives up, and goes home.  Or starves, stays put, and is slowly attrited away to nothing.

*A Note on Arrows*
A consideration when thinking of medieval archery is penetration of your arrows.  It's not like Total War where your maximum range is maximum deadliness and the only difference is accuracy.  The force of an arrow drops off DRAMATICALLY with distance.  To the point where, if your bow can shoot an arrow 100 meters (totally arbitrary number) You're only really dangerous to a man at 50 meters (any further away and a quilted jerkin is likely to stop your arrow) and it's only at 20ish meters that your arrows are accurate and powerful enough to do things like "kill a guy in mail with a shield and a helmet" reliably.  Even shooting downwards distance dramatically lowers punch.  For more, see [Armor punching myths](https://acoup.blog/2019/06/21/collections-punching-through-some-armor-myths/)

Comment: "Not enough to hold my position if THEIR archers kill my 6 buddies." Their archers *can't* kill your buddies; the trees are too tall for their arrows to reach that high. This is stated in the original question. Also, the archers can probably climb from tree to tree without ever returning to the ground.

Comment: @nick012000 "Also, the archers can probably climb from tree to tree without ever returning to the ground" - quotation needed. OP never said anything about tree roads and the trees in Star wars are well spaced between each other.

Comment: Reminds me of a friend who had not read the passage in the original _Dungeon Master's Guide_ about the danger of levitating above a combat. It was a learning experience for him.

Answer (score 6):

You said 2 large units of foot soldiers supported by archers. Your big problem will be retaining cohesiveness of any force entering a large/densely spaced forest.

A large mass of amour wearing footmen will not be able to remain in formation as they advance through the trees. Neither will their supporting archers (or indeed their baggage train).

If your opposing forces are;

a) expert archers/soldiers
b) familiar with/at home in the terrain and can exploit it to their advantage
c) pre-positioned along their enemies line of advance

Then they don't really even need to be positioned in the trees (or at least not all of them). This is especially the case if they have prepared the ground in advance by cutting down and bushes and small trees etc and piling them in pre-selected barriers through the forest, digging ditches and using smoke to confuse the enemy.

Assuming it is a large forest then unless they are *really* well drilled troops formation, command and control will fall apart fairly quickly. And that means you can use hit and run tactics to force them to withdraw.

**Footnote:** this strategy would leave the archers 'victorious' only in the sense that you can force the other side to withdraw after taking casualties. If their objective was to capture the forest and/or defeat your archers, they lose, this time.

What it doesn't do is eliminate the enemy force as a threat. At best you get a temporary stalemate (they can't get 'in' but you cant get 'out') pending further tactical or strategic developments by one side or the other.

Comment: I think what this world really needs is a large mass of amour.

Comment: This is fairly consistent with Rome's experience of fighting in Germania.

Comment: Depends on who selects the battle ground. Generally if on the offensive, Rome planned its military campaigns well in advance  with a view to fighting its battles at locations of its choosing. For the most part in Germania this was in and round settled areas where there was more open ground and their heavy infantry had the advantage. The one time a large Roman force got caught on the hop in close terrain (Teutoburg Forest) it didn't go well for them.

Answer (score 4):

I'm curious what on Earth are those archers perched in very tall trees supposed to do? They cannot possibly be effective against *"two large [infantry] units"*. Two large infantry units very stronly imply that they are marching on a wide road, or at least through large clearings; there is no way for two large infantry units to march through a forest -- they would lose unit cohesion, they would lose their way, they would stretch for miles and miles. No mentally competent commander would even think for a second of marching two large infantry units through a forest.

Which means that the archers are perched on their very tall trees on the sides of the road. And they are shooting downwards at a steep angle towards small targets. The infantry will simply raise their shields and march on, ignoring the foolish archers placed in an ineffective position by their foolish commanders. There is nothing preventing the invading force from simply marching on under their shields.

Medieval archers were effective when shooting what we would call indirect fire into the massed enemy force. That was the entire idea of medieval archery: put your archers on some small elevation behind a line of defending infantry, and let them shoot volleys of arrows into the massed enemy who *had to* come in a mass to try to pierce your infantry line. The enemy *could not* use their shields to protect themselves from the arrows coming from above on a curve because they had to fight your infantry. All in the open. Archers trying to hit individual soldiers through a forest of trees, no, that doesn't work.

Comment: You may need to make your archers some shields to use as they walk down this road.  Fortunately you are by a forest, and an improvised shield made of branches should be enough to shield them as your army walks by.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, putting archers is trees is not smart.  The correct tactics for the defenders would be to let the invaders into the forest then use hit and run ambush tactics against the invaders, starting with their baggage train.  The defenders will have no trouble tracking the invaders movements using the tall trees and knowledge of local terrain. Let them into the woods, then kill their scouts, destroy their food, destroy their tents and supplies, and make them afraid to move.  The archery skills of the defenders should be used as "snipers" to target anybody who shows any leadership.  An invading army is a threat so turn them into a bunch of guys who are cut off from support, hungry, and with nobody in charge to coordinate their movements.

In addition to observation, the best use of the high ground in the trees is to drop the occasional gift on the invader's heads.  Bonus points if the gift is filled with burning tree sap.

For the attackers, their best tools are fire and distance.  Burn a large swathe through the woods so the defenders have nowhere to hide and cannot get close to the main force without being seen.  Then move slow and steady while protecting the flanks.

Answer (score 2):

What exactly is stopping the attackers from using a [testudo formation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Testudo_formation) to protect a few guys with hatchets, who then fell any trees with archers in them?

It seems to me that the archers are trapped.  Look up some photos of redwood forests.  The trees aren't that close together, so they can't easily climb from one to the next.  Sure, the defenders may have built bridges between them, but so what?  Every time a tree is felled, any bridges connected to it will fall as well.  Imagine 3 trees connected in a line like, A-B-C.  If you cut down B, A and C are now isolated.

The infantry won't even be under that much fire, because only archers in the nearest trees will have a clear shot; the rest are blocked by other trees.

So how this will play out is that first, using the cover of testudo formations, the attackers will cut down the trees with the most bridge connections, the goal being to divide and trap as many archers as possible.  At each isolated tree, the attackers will hack away at the base of the tree, being sure to stand on the side furthest away from the rest of the archers, using the tree they're cutting as cover.  Any archers who survive the fall are likely to be easily dispatched.

Answer (score 1):

#### They'd have to take the fight to the treetops.

If the archers are living in fortified positions on the tops of these trees, the only real way for the invaders to take the fight to them is to climb the trees somehow, while the tree-dwellers are firing arrows and dropping munitions (hot oil, rocks, etc) down onto them.

Fire is unlikely to work, because we're talking about massive, living trees, and they're unlikely to be terribly flammable. Going around them is unlikely to work, because the tree-dwellers will have created methods to travel between these mega-trees without returning to the ground. Starving them out might work, but it's likely that these treetop communities will have some method of feeding themselves without needing to return to the ground (e.g. collecting rainwater, eating fruit, hunting treetop animals or their eggs, etc).

So, your invaders are basically reduced to the prospect of storming a giant castle located hundred of feet in the air, while under attack by the inhabitants of that castle. Most of the people involved are probably going to die in the process, simply due to how unforgiving the process of assaulting such a heavily fortified position is likely to be - unlike a conventional castle, you can't just knock down the walls with catapults or tunnel underneath them, so you'll need to pick one of the most difficult methods to take a castle available: scaling its walls while under fire.